# Correct dependson assignment in child resource does not seem to work

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have ARM template below which sometimes throws exception below which tells me that depends on in Extension is not working properly since extension shall only be deployed when parent VM is up. What am I doing wrong?

Entire template available here http://pastebin.com/VyDwGWWd

```
          {
            "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[concat('Lin', parameters('VirtualMachineName'), copyindex())]",
            "copy": {
              "name": "LinvirtualMachineLoop",
              "count": 3
            },
            "location": "[variables('VMResourceGroupLocation')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "LinnicLoop",
                "[variables('LogAnalyticsName')]",
                "LinuxMachinesAvailabilitySet"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "availabilitySet": {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets','LinuxMachinesAvailabilitySet')]"
        },
              "hardwareProfile": {
                "vmSize": "Standard_D4s_v3"
              },
              "osProfile": {
                "computerName": "[concat('Lin', parameters('VirtualMachineName'), copyindex())]",
                "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
              },
              "storageProfile": {
                "imageReference": "[variables('linuxImage')]",
                "osDisk": {
                  "createOption": "FromImage"
                }
              },
              "networkProfile": {
                "networkInterfaces": [
                  {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',concat('Linnic',copyindex()))]"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "resources": [
        {
          "type": "extensions",
          "name": "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring",
          "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
          "location": "[variables('VMResourceGroupLocation')]",
          "dependsOn": [
           "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat('Lin', parameters('VirtualMachineName'), copyindex()))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring",
            "type": "OmsAgentForLinux",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "1.6",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
"settings": {
              "workspaceId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', variables('LogAnalyticsName')), '2015-03-20').customerId]"
            },
            "protectedSettings": {
              "workspaceKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', variables('LogAnalyticsName')), '2015-03-20').primarySharedKey]"
            }
          }
        }
      ]


            },
```

Error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/LinWKDEMO0/extensions/Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring' under resource group 'WKDemo' was not found."
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats not what it says, it says that the extension was not found, not the VM was not found (it would say that if it would try to provision the extension before the vm). I'm fairly certain something else is trying to reference the extension. can you share the whole template?

Comment: Here is the whole template https://pastebin.com/VyDwGWWd

Comment: okay, after looking\testing your template, I dont see how you would get this error (and I certainly didnt get it). you need to add a couple of dependsOn here and there for the template to work start-to-end (at least lb should depend on vnet)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to 4c74356b41's response, you may set dependencies and check reference function as explained here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-not-found-errors

You may set required dependencies and set reference for Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring extension along with resourcegroup and give a try.